# Is there a best way to append a list values to a sublist of a list in R?

Tags: r, list

Say I have a list `l` containing sublists, and I would like to add an element of a list at the end of each sublist of that list.

```
> l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(2,1,4), c(4,7,6))
> l
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 4

[[3]]
[1] 4 7 6

> a <- list(3,5,7)
> a
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 7
```

What I would like is:

```
> l
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 4 7 6 7
```

I've tried several options, this one gets close, but it still doesn't compute the way I want to, as it adds the whole list at the end of the list.

```
l <- lapply(l, c, a)
```

Comment: With `lapply()`: `lapply(seq_along(l), \(i) c(l[[i]], a[[i]]))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes

```
mapply("c",l,a,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 4 7 6 7
```

Comment: Also `Map("c", l, a)`

Comment: Or `Map(c, l, a)`.

Answer (score 2):

A `purrr` way:

```
l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(2,1,4), c(4,7,6))
a <- list(3,5,7)

purrr::map2(l,a, append)
```

**Output**:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 4 7 6 7
```