# FALSE vs. F: Error mapply's SIMPLIFY argument: in SIMPLIFY=F

Tags: r, list, mapply

This Question refers to this [Is there a best way to append a list values to a sublist of a list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374654/is-there-a-best-way-to-append-a-list-values-to-a-sublist-of-a-list-in-r).

One of the solution is this:

```
a <- list(3,5,7)
l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(2,1,4), c(4,7,6))

mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY=F)
```

If I try to apply it on my machine I get the error:

```
Error in SIMPLIFY == "array" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

If I use this -> there is no error:

```
mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I want to understand why the error occurs in using `SIMPLIFY =F and not in SIMPLIFY = FALSE`.

I am using rstudio - cloud:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.3                         
year           2022                        
month          03                          
day            10                          
svn rev        81868                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
nickname       One Push-Up
```

Comment: I don't get the error when using `SIMPLIFY=F`.

Comment: Have you maybe got an `F` defined somewhere TarJae? What happens when you type `F` into the console?

Comment: Nor do I, even with `F <- "zzz"; mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY=F)`, although the output is different.

Comment: @Limey but you will get the error reproduced if you do `F <- function() 1; mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY=F)`

Comment: @tarjae, what is the result of `dput(F)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Indeed, I do.  I tried with `F` as a string and a data frame, but not as a function.

Comment: Sorry had to leave immediately my pc. So `dput(F)` gives:  `function (x, n = 1, ...) 
UseMethod("F")`.

Comment: And after cleaning my workspace and restarting R, the error does not occur!!!

Comment: @TarJae I wonder which package has a generic function called `F` defined? That seems to me to be asking for trouble!

Comment: @Allan Cameron: I had a look in the environment before cleaning the workspace. Interstingly I did not find a function called `F`. But with your explanation now it is clear why the error occurs. Unfortunately I don't know where this function `F` came from.

Comment: @TarJae probably you loaded `library(collapse);  there is `F` function there.  I can reproduce your error `> mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY=F)#
Error in SIMPLIFY == "array" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a fresh R session, this error isn't reproducible:

```r
a <- list(3,5,7)
l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(2,1,4), c(4,7,6))

mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY=F)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 1 4 5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 4 7 6 7
```

However, we can replicate your error by overwriting `F` with a function:

```r
F <- function() {}; mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY=F)
#> Error in SIMPLIFY == "array" : 
#>   comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Which suggests that you have a function somewhere on your search path called `F`.

The reason that we can guess it is a function rather than, say, a data frame or a vector, is that we would only get this error if there is something being passed to `SIMPLIFY` that does not have a method defined for the `==` operator, and a function is the most likely candidate (especially since it is called `F`)

If you look at the source code for `mapply`, you will see that the `SIMPLIFY` argument gets passed to `simplify2array` if and only if it does not evaluate to an atomic `FALSE`:

```r
function (FUN, ..., MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    dots <- list(...)
    answer <- .Internal(mapply(FUN, dots, MoreArgs))
    if (USE.NAMES && length(dots)) {
        if (is.null(names1 <- names(dots[[1L]])) && is.character(dots[[1L]])) 
            names(answer) <- dots[[1L]]
        else if (!is.null(names1)) 
            names(answer) <- names1
    }
    if (!isFALSE(SIMPLIFY)) 
        simplify2array(answer, higher = (SIMPLIFY == "array"))
    else answer
}
```

If it is not an atomic `FALSE`, the `SIMPLIFY` argument is then tested for equality to the string `"array"` using the `==` operator. If the object cannot be tested for equality with a character string, we will get this error.

I think this question is a great example of why one should never use `F` as a variable name in R, and why one should always use `FALSE` instead of `F`.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP mentioned that they didn't create any function `F` in the console, it could be coming from loading `collapse` package

```
library(collapse)
```

and then we check `?F`

> `flag` is an S3 generic to compute (sequences of) lags and leads. `L` and `F` are wrappers around flag representing the lag- and lead-operators...

Thus, the error can be reproduced

```
> mapply(c, l, a, SIMPLIFY=F)
Error in SIMPLIFY == "array" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```